# pass cck email value to webform block

Tags: nodes, entities, webforms

I currently have 2 webforms displayed on a page - these are inserted dynamically from a node.tpl.php file.

However, I also have a cck field on the current node for an email address - I would like to be able to pass this email value directly to the "Email To" field of the webform.

This would create a new email recipient depending on which node you were viewing. For example:

The "About Us" page contained the field "email: hello@mydomain.com" - therefore the webform loaded in the sidebar would be sent to this address.

The "Location" page contains the field "email: location@mydomain.com" - now this would be the email address that receives any submissions from that page.

The idea is to have 1 webform and dynamically change the email its sent to based on a cck field. Is this possible at all?

Thanks,
Garry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your webform add an "email field" for the recipient (say `email_recipient`).
2. Go to `node/123/webform/emails` to set the recipient to be your previously created field.
3. Create a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to put the email address you your webform field.

   ```
   <?php
   function CUSTOM_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     //you need to set up a CUSTOM module to store this.
     //use devel with dsm($form); to figure the name of each field
     if ($form['#id'] == 'webform-client-form-123') {
       //load the node from the url
       if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
         $node_email = node_load(arg(1));
         //set your webform field to your email
         $form['submitted']['con_email_recipient']['#default_value'] 
              = $node_email->field_email_recipient[0]['value'];
       }
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Add some CSS to hide the field, and it should work, code untested but I'm pretty confident about the steps, also have a look at [Working with Default Values](http://drupal.org/node/296453#webform-url-default).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have setup my custom module and added the recipient email field to my form. However, I am receiving an error with your code "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in..." I also don't see where my CCK email field is being inserted into the webform. Do you have anymore instructions? Cheers, Garry.

Comment: @Garry which line cause the error ? Do you see your recipient field being populated with your CCK ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else comes up with this problem, the problem is this line:

```
if (arg(0) = 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
```

should be

```
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
```

Comment: Your post not attempt to answer this question, explain in brief!!

Comment: Yep I fixed it, thanks for the bug report ;) but it should be a comment on my answer as yours isn't a proper answer.