# Which webform hook and how use to set programmatically webform target email?

Tags: 6, webforms

First part as in title and how to detect different webforms?

Ex. function name - hook_webform_submission_actions

Replace 'webform' with form id?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to customize the target email, webform do this quite easily.
Go to `node/123/webform/emails` (where 123 is you nid) and there you can configure the recipients.
The option "component value" allows you for example to set the email regarding a select list. Configure a select list for the subject, put these values in the option textarea:

```
contact@example.com|General inquiries
marketing@example.com|Marketing
```

Then when the user will use webform the email will be sent to the direction chosen in the subject list.

If you want something more advanced, have a look at my previous answer in ["pass cck email value to webform block"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/5222/594). This will help you to detect different webform (using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).